# change sketch from controlling 8 stepper motors to 8 solenoids

Tags: arduino-mega, relay

I am looking to see if I can change the attached sketch which controls 8 stepper motors to just switching 8 relays for a weaving loom which we have, unfortunately making this change is well above my paygrade lol. I am using an arduino mega and 8 channel relay board which will in turn trip the solenoids which the loom already has attached, thanks for any help

This is the Sketch im trying to alter

```c++
// Loom interface for Ashford Dobby interface (using 8 stepper motors):
// Arduino lines 0 & 1 to USB interface
// line 13 Is foot pedal
// 14-43 are motor controls

// General definitions:
#define MAX_CHARS 80
#define DEBUG 0
#define MOTORS 8
#define IDENTITY "Generic Dobby Interface (Jones Stepper Motor Dobby)\n"

// Data controlling motor positions, states, etc:
const long MOTOR_DELAY=900;                                                      // Time delay between motor steps (reduce till shafts move reliably)
const long  SHAFT_UP=8*170, SHAFT_DOWN=0 ;                                       // Number of motor steps required to raise the shafts
unsigned long shaft_state=0x00000000, shaft_cue=0xffffffff;                      // tracking current & next desired states of shaft controls
long MotorActual[MOTORS], MotorWant[MOTORS];                                     // Current & desired position for each of the motors

// Definition of which Output pins connect to which motor
char MotorPin[MOTORS][4]=                                                        // Motors 1,3,5,7 on right, 2,4,6,8 on left: left side reverses direcion
              { {14,15,16,17}, {18,21,20,19}, {22,23,24,25}, {26,29,28,27},      // Motors 1-4
                {30,31,32,33}, {34,37,36,35}, {38,39,40,41}, {42,45,44,43}};     // Motors 5-8

unsigned long NextMotorUpdate=0;                                                 // Timer for when next motor step occurs
const int ADVANCE  =13;                                                          // input pin for footswitch (has pullup, switch contact only)

// Serial (USB) interface
// Serial interface is a "Generic" dobby interface:
// Host sends which shafts should be activated for current shot
// Shafts will raise when the foot switch is activated
// Shafts return when foot switch is released, and the "Advance" command returned to host
// Also responds to "?" with the "IDENTITY" identified above, shows host who's out here

int serial_chars=0;                                                              // Number of characters in the serial input buffer
char serial_string[MAX_CHARS]="";                                                // Serial input buffer
char Message[MAX_CHARS]="";                                                      // Output message buffer
long serial_time=0;                                                              // Used to close serial string on timeout (timer)
const int serial_timeout=100;                                                    // Digest Serial string after timeout
char serial_idle=1;                                                              // Tracks activity on the serial bus
char HostPresent = 1;                                                            // set when some host is identified
int Button_state=1;                                                              // tracks changes in floor-switch state


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Send shaft controls to hardware
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void set_motor(char m,char state)                                            // Lowest level function to handle step in motors
    {
//   sprintf(Message,"M %d @ state %d\n",m,state);
//   Serial.write(Message);
     switch(state)
     {
      case 0:                                                                    // Set motor inactive
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], 0);
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], 0);
      break;

      case 1:                                                                    // Set motor State 1
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], 1);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], 0);
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], 0);
      break;

      case 2:                                                                    // Set motor state 2
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], 1);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], 1);
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], 0);
      break;

      case 3:                                                                    // Set motor state 3
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], 1);
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], 0);
      break;

      case 4:                                                                    // Set motor state 4
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], 1);
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], 1);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], 0);
      break;

      case 5:                                                                    // Set motor state 5
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], 0);
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], 1);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], 0);
      break;

      case 6:                                                                    // Set motor state 6
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], 0);
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], 1);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], 1);
      break;

      case 7:                                                                    // Set motor state 7
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], 0);
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], 1);
      break;

      case 8:                                                                    // Set motor state 8
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], 1);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], 0);
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], 0);    digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], 1);
      break;
     }
    }
 
   char set_motors()                                                            // Set all motors to new motor state - called for each motor step on any motor
    {                                                                            // return indicates if any motor is still active
     int m=0;
     long setting, entry_setting;
     char active=0;

     while(m<MOTORS)
     {
                                                                                 // Check for necessary directional movement
      entry_setting=setting=MotorActual[m];
      if(setting==MotorWant[m])       setting=setting;
      else if(setting<MotorWant[m])   setting++;
      else                            setting--;
                                                                                 // Send update setting controls
      if((entry_setting!=MotorWant[m]))
      {
       active=1;
       MotorActual[m]=setting;                                                   // update actual for move in progress
       setting=(setting&7)+1;                                                    // set_motor state 0 is inactive, 1-8 are active
       set_motor(m,setting);                                                     // Set new motor state
      }
      m++;                                                                       // Next motor
     }
     if(active==0)
     {                                                                           // If done kill power to the motors that are back in passive state
      m=0;
      while(m<MOTORS)
      {
       if(MotorActual[m]==SHAFT_DOWN)set_motor(m,0);                             // set motor inactive
       m++;
      }
     }
     return active;
    }

    char run_motors()                                                            // Higher level function to set motors to desired positions
    {                                                                            // return indicates if motors are active or idle
     char active=1;
     if(micros()>=NextMotorUpdate)
     {                                                                           // time to update the motor positions
      active=set_motors();                                                       // Update all motors
      NextMotorUpdate=micros()+MOTOR_DELAY;                                      // set clock for next update
     }
     return active;
    }

    void set_shafts(unsigned long shafts)                                        // Called to set desired motor positions based on which shafts were requested
    {                                                                            // This assumes all shafts move the same amount, they really don't need to
     unsigned long bit_mask=1;
     int i=0;
     while(i<MOTORS)
     {
      if(shafts&bit_mask)MotorWant[i]=SHAFT_UP;
      else               MotorWant[i]=SHAFT_DOWN;
//    sprintf(Message,"M %d @ want %d\n",i,MotorWant[i]>>8);
//    Serial.write(Message);
      i++;
      bit_mask=bit_mask<<1;
     }
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Preset- Called on initialization
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void preset()                                                                // Could raise all shafts to show it's working, etc.
    {                                                                            // This version doesn't do anything, default will lift all shafts when the foot switch is pressed before anything else is requested
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SERIAL INTERFACE (USB) FUNCTIONS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                                                                 // USB input commands:
                                                                                 // 1,2,3,n            Set shafts 1,2,3,n
                                                                                 // ?                  ID request, respond with ID
    unsigned long get_shafts(char* command)                                      // Input is series of numbers, comma seperated, for shafts to raise
    {                                                                            // returns word indicating which shafts were identified in string
     int chars=strlen(command);                                                  // Number of characters in input string
     int i=0;
     unsigned long shafts=0, bits;                                               // Sets bits for shafts indicated
     char shaft=0, digit=0, character;

     while(i<=chars)                                                             // loop through all characters in command
     {
      character=command[i];

      if((character==',')||(i==chars))
      {                                                                          // have field seperator or end of string, not shaft desired
       if((shaft>0)&&(shaft<=32))
       {                                                                         // 'shafts' notes this shaft is required
        bits=1<<shaft-1;
        shafts|=bits;
        shaft=0;
       }
      }
      else if(('0'<=character)&&(character<='9'))
      {                                                                          // have digit
       character&=0x0f;                                                          // reduce to decimal
       shaft=shaft*10+character;
      }
      else if((character==' ')||(character=='\n'));                              // ignore spaces/returns
      else
      {
       Serial.println("Invalid Character detected in command:");                 // debug display of command extracted
       Serial.println(command);                                                  // debug display of command extracted
       i=chars;                                                                  // quit, got crap
      }
      i++;
     }
     return shafts;
    }

    void digest_serial(char* command)                                            // Main serial response function
    {
     int chars=strlen(command);                                                  // Number of characters in command

     if(chars>0)
     {                                                                           // If something to do go digest the input
      HostPresent=1;                                                             // note that there's something out there talking to me
      if(('0'<=command[0])&&(command[0]<='9'))                                   // go number, should be shafts
       shaft_cue=get_shafts(command);                                            // convert ASCII string to binary word
      else  if((command[0]=='c')||(command[0]=='t'))                             // test command to cycle valves
       preset();                                                                 // cycle through the valves (nothing defined for this loom, could implement shaft self test, etc)
      else if(command[0]=='?')
      {                                                                          // Have a "Who are You?" kind of command, tell host who we are
       char message[256]=IDENTITY;                                               // Build primary Identity command
       message[strlen(message)-1]=0;                                             // delete return in line
       sprintf(message,"%s  [Solenoid state = 0x%3x]\n",message,shaft_state);    // note what we'll do when button is pressed
       Serial.write(message);                                                    // Send identity with current switch state to host (for troubleshooting)
      }
     }
    }

    void serial_input()
    {                                                                            // High level Serial processing
     char inChar;
     char command[MAX_CHARS]="";

     while((Serial.available()>0))
     {                                                                           // Get serial command from host (character by character)
      inChar=char(Serial.read());
      serial_string[serial_chars]=inChar;
      serial_chars++;
      serial_string[serial_chars]=0;
      serial_time=millis();
     }
     if((serial_chars>0)&&(serial_idle)&&((serial_string[serial_chars-1]=='\n')||(millis()>(serial_time+serial_timeout))))
     {                                                                           // If have a command, go digest it
      serial_idle=0;
      strcpy(command,serial_string);
      serial_chars=0;
      serial_string[0]=0;
//    Serial.println(command);                                                   // debug display of command extracted
      digest_serial(command);
                                                                                 // done with last command, clear the input buffers
      serial_idle=1;                                                             // ready for more serial input
     }
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// /
// Foot Switch monitor  - set shafts/tell host to advance
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// /
    void monitor_button()
    {                                                                            // check for button push to advance, sent only when button pushed (not held)
     char state=digitalRead(ADVANCE);                                            // read state of foot switch (0=active, 1=inactive)

     if(state==0)
     {                                                                           // button is pressed,
      set_shafts(shaft_cue);                                                     // Set motor desired states from the list of shafts desired for this shot
      run_motors();                                                              // Go run the motors to make it happen
     }
     else
     {                                                                           // button is not pressed,
      set_shafts(0);                                                             // Set motor desired states back to reset condition
      run_motors();                                                              // Make it happen
      if(Button_state!=state)
       Serial.write("ADVANCE\n");                                                // Send "Advance" when foot switch is released
     }
     if(state!=Button_state)                                                     // Check if button has changed state
      delay(500);                                                                // Wait half a second on changes to debounce switch
     Button_state=state;                                                         // Track current state of the button to look for changes
    }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TOP LEVEL FUNCTIONS - SETUP & LOOP                                                                                        //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void setup()
    {
     char m;                                                                     // Motor indicator

                                                                                 // USB Interface to host computer
     Serial.begin(9600);                                                         // start serial port at 9600 bps:
     Serial.print(IDENTITY);                                                     // print message on serial monitor

                                                                                 // Motor Controls
                                                                                 // set motor controls for all motors
     m=0;
     while(m<MOTORS)
     {
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][0], LOW);                                         // set low
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][1], LOW);                                         // set low
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][2], LOW);                                         // set low
      digitalWrite(MotorPin[m][3], LOW);                                         // set low
      pinMode(MotorPin[m][0], OUTPUT);                                           // Set as output bit
      pinMode(MotorPin[m][2], OUTPUT);                                           // Jumble order to keep motor from moving
      pinMode(MotorPin[m][1], OUTPUT);                                           // Set as output bit
      pinMode(MotorPin[m][3], OUTPUT);                                           // Set as output bit
      MotorWant[m]=MotorActual[m]=0;                                             //
      m++;
     }

      pinMode(ADVANCE, INPUT_PULLUP);                                            // Set as input pin to handle the foot switch
      preset();                                                                  // "self test" - note it's alive
      unsigned long T0=millis();                                                 // Note start up time
     }



    void loop()
    {
     serial_input();                                                             // check the serial interface, handle if it comes in
     monitor_button();                                                           // check for button push
    }
```

Comment: it's not possible to do what you want without knowing how the solenoid action replaces the motor action ... basically, what the motors do, at what time do they do it, and how do the solenoids replace the function that the motors do

Comment: comments are not part of the code ... they should not be interweaved into the code ... cleaned up the program listing for you

Comment: Hi Jsotola, thankyou for your reply, all the solenoid will do is activate when the motor would normally, ie instead of the motor engaging and doing x number of rotations the solenoid will just engage, this is triggered by the software that is running on windows to create and run a pr determined pattern, then when the foot switch is triggered the solenoid will disengage and the pc software will move to the next step in the pattern and engage the correct solenoids. sorry about all of the comments as these were already in the sketch that I found.

Comment: lots of comments are a very good thing, but they should not clutter the code ... that's all I'm saying

Comment: I always thought the best place for comments are at the beginning of the functions. Good comments there indicate thought went into segmenting the task into nicely organized functions. However, even the giants like NXP and STMicro do not regularly do this in their code. Also, comments like "Set motor State 1" are worthless. Seasoned programmers will instantly comment: "That's obvious ... but what is 'State 1' ... that's the real question / comment to be made."

Answer (score 1):

- The assumed goal is to automate a Weaving Loom using solenoids instead of steppers.
- [This video](https://youtu.be/YcQjRLs0cXc) claims a 3kg pull is necessary. It may be difficult to find an appropriate / economical solenoid with that kind of pull, stroke distance & rated for continuous duty (hold its position for a prolonged period of time without harming its self from heat related problems).
- If sourcing such a solenoid is not a problem, there are only 2 functions in the above code that control the steppers. "set_motor" and "setup". Change those to activate / deactivate solenoids.
- Also, this might be harder, remove the code that cycles the steppers into / out-of position. You don't need that w/the solenoids.

Answer (score 0):

I would first figure out what each stepper motor code segment is doing, in overview. Think of viewing the process while standing back from it and describe the *reason* that code segment is there, more than what, specifically, it does - what it's relationship is to the process, not to the motor.

Move those motor segments into functions, and put function calls where the motor segments used to be.

Now replace the motor code inside each function with solenoid code. This is why we wanted an abstract overview of those motor segments. In each function, you'll write solenoid-specific code that has that same relationship to the overall process as the motor code did, but you'll tailor the specifics to the solenoids.